# Why Blocks are Missing or Skipped on NEAR

Tags: nearprotocol, indexer, nearprotocol-validator

I was wondering how come some blocks exist but some don't? It seems like they get skipped and I'm unsure as to why. For example:

[87868936](https://testnet.nearblocks.io/blocks/2bU11iHyVh3kut5cX3vsBe5u6WeNVzHpRFFLE8BdRWC5) exists and so does [87868938](https://testnet.nearblocks.io/blocks/DgMHH7VLY1L5uwrn44y9oaqCCEPPDmMsWk4kZBHqqQ43) but 87868938 does **not**. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ben. I understand you are doing good work. But your question is not a good fit for StackOverflow's Q&A format. I suggest you study how StackOverflow works.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it needs to be a question.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I would suggest Ben move the text beginning from the second paragraph to the answer and keep this question, it's a good one.

Comment: I've changed my answer to be more Q&A style. Thanks for the feedback, I'm just starting to get into SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason behind this is quite simple. Sometimes the validator who is responsible for the production of the block can't complete it for some reason (lag, node has crashed, etc...)

The network will wait for some reasonable amount time and then passes the queue to the next validator and it will produce its block with the planned height. There's nothing weird or bad in skipped blocks, it's by design.